# Rspec - How to include a shared_context in a shared_examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have the following Rspec structure

shared_context.rb

```
shared_context 'do something' do

end
```

test_spec.rb

```
shared_examples 'testing' do 

end

describe 'do something' do 
   it_should_behave_like 'testing'
   end
end
```

the **shared_examples** is dependent on **shared_context** . How do i include shared_context in shared_examples.

I tried using **include_context**, and tried **require 'support/shared_context.rb'** and they didn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just requiring the file should work. Perhaps its not finding the file in question, you should use require `require Rails.root.join('spec/support/shared_context.rb')` to be sure.

I normally require the entire spec/support directory in my spec_helper.rb

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

Comment: I have already included the Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f } in my spec_helper ..

Comment: Can you clarify further, what do you mean by didn't work? Could you give the error you are getting.

Comment: I am getting the following error -   undefined local variable or method `variable_name'

Comment: The `variable_name` method is not mentioned in the question. Can you add more details to the question?